# Obtener todos los registros sin repetir id

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero hacer una consulta para obtener todos los datos de mi tabla, pero sin que el idPrincipal se repita, pero obteniendo los demas idPrincipal

es decir en mi tabla tengo el campo

```
id auto increment
idPrincipal
idFinal
sent
msg
```

el idPrincipal puede tener id 1 o 2 o 3 infinidad de veces, pero quiero hacer una consulta donde sólo se muestren 1 sola vez con el último dato que estos tengan.

mi consulta que realicé fue:

```
    SELECT idFinal, sent, msg 
DISTINCT idPrincipal from messages
WHERE idFinal = 28 
ORDER BY sent DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

pero al ejecutar el query me marca error, estoy usando `MYSQL`

> **EDITADO**

Mi base de datos consta de lo siguiente ya con datos reales...

```
tabla usuarios 
idUsuario,
nombre,

Tabla messages
idMsg,
idEmitter FK usuarios
idReceiver FK usuarios
messages,
nombre,
sent DATE
seenReceiver
```

quiero que aparezcan los mensajes que tiene `idReceiver` con `seenReceiver = 0` pero obviando que se muestre el ultimo mensaje del `idReceiver` sin repetirlo ya que de la manera en que yo generaba la consulta me generaba los registros e imprimia todos los que tenian `seen 0`

un ejemplo de mi resultado era

```
idEmitter 1 'mensaje' 'sent' idReceiver 28
idEmitter 1 'mensaje' 'sent' idReceiver 28
idEmitter 1 'mensaje' 'sent' idReceiver 28
idEmitter 3 'mensaje' 'sent' idReceiver 28
idEmitter 3 'mensaje' 'sent' idReceiver 28
idEmitter 3 'mensaje' 'sent' idReceiver 28
idEmitter 5 'mensaje' 'sent' idReceiver 28
idEmitter 5 'mensaje' 'sent' idReceiver 28
idEmitter 5 'mensaje' 'sent' idReceiver 28
```

yo solo quiero que aparezca el ultimo mensaje que envio el idEmitter

```
idEmitter 1 'mensaje' 'sent' idReceiver 28
idEmitter 3 'mensaje' 'sent' idReceiver 28
idEmitter 5 'mensaje' 'sent' idReceiver 28
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar

Comment: te dejo una referencia de como usar el DISTINCT espero que te sirva.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: ¿Cuando dices que se muestre **el ultimo dato que tengan** te refieres al que tenga el atributo `id auto increment` más alto verdad? Además, te falta el `FROM` en tu consulta

Comment: Estás intentando crear un chat, verdad?

Comment: @ReneLimon Gracias por responder, pero cuando me refiero al ultimo dato quiero que sea como lo hago en el ejemplo que sea por el ultimo sent(Fecha mas reciente)

Comment: Lo que considero que esperas lograr es que se muestre el último mensaje de cada conversación existente según ID.

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos los chats también pueden crearse usando PHP y AJAX. No es muy recomendado pero **sí** es posible y bajo un uso moderado o pequeño puede ser empleado. Hablar de WebSockets es otro cuento.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz asi es! pero por principio solo maestro el ultimo que se mando y ya en otra parte (single) se muestre todos los mensajes que se referencias con el idPrincipal y el idFinal (Ese query ya lo tengo)

Comment: @MáximaAlekz de hecho tengo uno con ajax pero al momento en que quiero hacer el select de las cosas no me muestra nada, y como es un poco urgente jeje opte por hacerlo de otra manera (que creo que me lo complique mas)

Comment: Entonces a ver si logro entender correctamente lo que preguntas... Necesitas que te arroje el último mensaje por fecha descendente (La más reciente) y que se base en los ID Principal y Final.

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos ahí te respondí :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me voy a apoyar directamente en `idMsg`, no lo has especificado en tú última edición pero entiendo que es un autonumérico, esto me asegura cual es el más viejo o más nuevo de forma más directa y segura (x fecha siempre tendríamos el problema en el caso de fechas iguales).

La solución pasa por generar una subconsulta con el máximo `idMsg` por cada `idReceiver` y `idEmitter`, luego simplemente un Join a dicha subconsulta, algo así:

```
SELECT  m.idEmitter, 
        m.messages, 
        m.sent, 
        m.idReceiver 
    FROM messages m
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT idEmitter,
                        idReceiver,
                        max(idMsg) AS idMsg
                        FROM messages
                        WHERE seenReceiver = 0
                        GROUP BY idEmitter, idReceiver
        ) mm
        ON m.idMsg = mm.idMsg
        AND m.idEmitter = mm.idEmitter
        AND m.idReceiver = mm.idReceiver
    WHERE m.idReceiver = 28 
          AND seenReceiver = 0
```

Espero te sea útil..

Comment: tengo una duda ¿por que pones `messages m`?

Comment: Es un [alias](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php) para la tabla, hace la escritura más sencilla y al usar JOIN son más que necesarios.

Comment: ooh okok, he editado mi pregunta

Comment: Cesar, ahí reedite mi respuesta con los nuevos datos que aportaste, estaba en la duda de hacerlo, por que la edición fue bastante significativa en cuanto a los cambios. En el futuro te recomiendo plantear de entrada tu pregunta de forma más concreta y con ejemplos como lo has hecho en esta nueva edición. De esa forma seguramente tengas más éxito a la hora de obtener una respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Master!!!! muchisimas gracias mi estimado, me ayudo demasiado y aprendi de igual manera demasiado, jamas habia hecho un query asi :D

Comment: De casualidad sabras como sacar el conteo como para la notificacion?

Comment: Si te refieres a la cantidad de registros por `idMsg`, puedes agregar la función `COUNT(1) AS 'Cantidad'`  en la consulta del `INNER JOIN`. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE idPrincipal = ? AND idFinal = ? ORDER BY sent DESC LIMIT 1
```

Cambia los signos de interrogación por las ID correspondientes.

Cuando inidico `LIMIT 1` estoy diciendo que sólo muestre un resultado. Siendo el primero la más reciente inserción segun los ID que designamos, da como resultado el último mensaje según fecha y también con ésta consulta se obtienen **todas** las columnas.

Comment: La consulta parece correcta, pero ¿por qué seleccionas **todas** las columnas? El OP al parecer, sólo quiere estas columnas: `idFinal, sent, msg, idPrincipal `.

Comment: *Quiero hacer una consulta para obtener todos los datos de mi tabla*

Comment: @MáximaAlekz El resultado fue mas o menos el que esperaba pero no al 100, ya que solo me manda precisamente el ultimo. ejemplo... si hay como idPrincipal 1, 5, 10 y cada uno se repite muchas veces  quiero que se muestre 1, 5, 10 pero no que salga 1,1,1,5,5,5,10,10,10. Espero haberme explicado